# Where do I find the database's own current timezone in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, timezone

I'm trying to figure out where I can get the "CST" or "PST" et al value that's associated with the current timestamp in mysql.  I'm looking to use `convert_tz` and I want to convert to whatever the database is set to (it will change depending on daylight savings time).  There must be an easy way to get at this string, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME='TIME_ZONE'
```

my setup says SYSTEM which I assume means it's using the OS's timezone.

Comment: Quite strangely, that seems to work... convert_tz(some_timestamp, 'SYSTEM', 'US/Pacific') does what I want, even though it's wildly unintuitive. Thanks very much.